# Using Dropbox to to backup Windows installation media

Tags: dropbox, windows-10

I have recently just completed a clean install of Windows 10 after getting my free upgrade. I have my Windows 10 boot device as a USB in case I need to ever reinstall (yes, I know that the upgrade is tied to your current hardware and that if I upgrade my motherboard I'll need a new licence key for Win10) but I have a bad habit of misplacing USB devices and I don't have a spare external drive.

My question is this: **can I use Dropbox to store Windows 10 installation files from my USB stick and simply copy them to another device should I ever need to reinstall?**

Comment: Why wouldn't you be able to, assuming you have enough space?

Comment: I wasn't sure if there was any other "behind the scenes" stuff that went on when creating the boot device. Space is no issue, just wanted to check that a cut and dry copy and paste with all the files will do the trick.

Comment: Assuming you copy whatever hidden files there are, it would work, *theoretically*. It'd be a better idea to create an *image* of the boot disk and save that to dropbox.

Comment: I would also go the image way.  Then you are sure to get everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This *could* be a better way of doing it, rather than a copy and paste from a USB, because you have the bootloader that you can't copy and paste (normally).

First, find if your computer is 32 bit or 64 bit:

1. Go to `Start -> Settings -> System -> About`
2. If `System type` displays `64-bit operating system` then you are 64 bit, otherwise you are 32 bit. You will also need your `Edition` later on.

Now, download the [media creation tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10). There are two options, choose the one corresponding to if your computer is 32 or 64 bit.

Run the utility, then select the second option, `Create installation media for another PC`. Select the `Edition` you found above, the language you need, and the Architecture as the "bits" you found above. Click next, and select ISO file. Then, save the ISO on your Desktop. After it finishes downloading, creating, etc., close the "Windows 10 setup" window.

Now you can transfer the ISO (on your Desktop, assuming you saved it there) to your Dropbox. When you need it, download the ISO from Dropbox, and [burn it to a DVD](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/write-a-cd-dvd-image-or-iso/). Then, insert the DVD into the affected PC, and boot from the DVD.

Comment: Will try this after work and accept if it works :)